# How do I make a discord bot that logs chats in a specific channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a Discord botm but I can't figure out how I can have the bot send a message when something is being sent in any channel, the message would basically be [user] sent [message] in [channel]

(I am using replit.com to write the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    #listen for message
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        else:
            #choose channel you want to receive bot message
            channel = self.get_channel(int: channel_id_here)
            #send message
            await channel.send(f'{message.author} sent "{message.content}" in {message.channel}')

client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

For find your channel id: https://docs.statbot.net/docs/faq/general/how-find-id/

Comment: I believe that worked. I do have one more problem, when I try to run the bot it doesn't work because it says "undefined name 'Bot'. 
https://gyazo.com/0ec10e8fe22c0e767d9aaf4c358c61bf

Comment: What is your "keep_alive()"? yes guy you need to end your code by "client = MyClient" and "client.run(os.environ["TOKEN"])". I understand what you wanted to do but the class name is not "Bot" but "MyClient". If you want to do it this way I think you can do "MyClien().run(os.environ["TOKEN"])" or just change the name of the class to Bot like "class Bot(discord.Client)"

Comment: It looks like there is no errors but when I try to run it I get this in the web view: https://gyazo.com/e5d5df96dfef08a03c421a90b3d242e3

Comment: try to delete your keep_alive()

Comment: This is what I get now: https://gyazo.com/598d1099f614bda0a92369cf226f8348

Comment: This is how it works for me on my repplit https://ibb.co/FB0L8FK

Comment: I edited the code a bit so that it pings the message author and so that it ignores bots but your code worked, thanks for that! https://gyazo.com/36e8b3b8a01f1d1d03f92dcc96d0e2a4

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by getting the channel id of the channel you want to get the messages from, and the id of the channel you want the messages to be logged in. Add the following code in the on_message function:

```
#id of channel to get messages from
cid1 = channel id goes here

#id of channel to log messages to
cid2 = other channel id goes here

#getting channel object from id:
logc = await client.get_channel(cid1)

if message.author == self.user:
        return
if message.channel.id == cid1:
        await logc.send(f'{message.author} sent {message} in {logc.name}')
```